# How get the unicode string as argument to visual C++ MFC project?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

I have a Visual C++ MFC project which will open the PDF File. I need to lauch this Project EXE from Python code with file path as argument. The File path is an Unicode string e.g. **u'C:\\Desktop\\Rahul\xadShikhare.pdf'** ("\xad" is SOFT_HYPHEN unichar number 173, Actual file path is C:\Desktop\Rahul-Shikahre.pdf).

I want to pass this unicode string to **OpenDocumentFil(LPCTSTR file_path)** function of **CWin class**  which will open the file.

**How to read an unicode string (string have SHOF_HYPHE unichar) from command line in Visual C++ and store it into LPCTSTR variable?**

I tried with following code but it showing error as Path not exist.

```
LPWSTR cmd_arg = GetCommandLineW();

//---This is for removing Application exe name from cmd_arg
wstring all_args = cmd_arg;
int position = all_args.find(L" ");
wstring file_path = L"";

if (position > 0)
{
    file_path = all_args.substr(position + 1);
    file_path.append(L"");
    MessageBox(NULL, file_path.c_str(), L"", MB_OK);
}
//--------------

if (file_path != L"")
{
    OpenDocumentFile(file_path.c_str());
}
```

The above code is giving the problem only if the arguments have SOFT-HYPHE as unicode char in cmd_arg string.

Comment: Is your application compiled as a Unicode application?

Comment: Instead of writing code to manipulate the original input string, why not first hard-code the name and see if `OpenDocumentFile` works?  You're showing a lot of irrelevant code, such as command-line processing.  If the issue is with `OpenDocumentFile`, then focus the attention to that call with a known name to see if it works correctly.

Comment: Side note: You don't have to do you own command line parsing: [CommandLineToArgvW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes, and removing completely the command-line processing, then the issue takes a known path -- either the command-line processing is faulty, or the OpenDocumentFile is faulty even when given a good name.